# ARM Clang: couldn't allocate output register for constraint 'w'

Tags: android-ndk, arm, clang, inline-assembly, neon

```cpp
uint8_t* dataPtr;
uint8x8x4_t dataVec;
__asm__ __volatile__( "vldmia %1, %h0" : "=w"( dataVec ) : "r"( dataPtr ) );
```

Above ARM inline assembly code works fine when compiled with Android NDK using `GCC` toolchain for `armeabi-v7a` ABI. However, I get following compiler error when I switch to `Clang`

> error: couldn't allocate output register for constraint 'w'

According to [LLVM docs](https://llvm.org/docs/LangRef.html#supported-constraint-code-list), constraint 'w' can be used for SIMD register on ARM target.

Am I missing something? Has anyone encountered this issue? Is it a bug in LLVM?

Thanks

Comment: Sounds like you haven't told gcc to enable the simd extensions.  Also, you might want to consider using builtins instead of asm.

Comment: @DavidWohlferd : I am passing compiler flag LOCAL_CFLAGS += -mfpu=neon. I have more NEON intrinsic and assembly code which compiles fine. That's how I know NEON optimization is enabled.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the LLVM Docs:

> The constraint codes are, in general, expected to behave the same way
>   they do in GCC. LLVM’s support is often implemented on an ‘as-needed’
>   basis, to support C inline asm code which was supported by GCC. A
>   mismatch in behavior between LLVM and GCC likely indicates a bug in
>   LLVM.

Maybe it's a good idea for you to report this on https://bugs.llvm.org/